# How to update Json Data on same key in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

```
  var mainObject = {
        a: "a",
        b: "b",
        c: "c",
        d: "d"
    }

var testObject = {
    a: "",
    b: ""
}
```

I want result like:

```
var testObject = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b"
}
```

Comment: Explain clearly

Comment: Assuming you know the keys of both objects, you could do `testObject.a = mainObject.a` and `testObject.b = mainObject.b`, but your question is really unclear so i'm not sure of what you want to achieve

Comment: Nah everytime i don't know the keys of both object.
problem solved at the end thanks for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this using for loop and `hasOwnProperty` function

```js
var mainObject = {
        a: "a",
        b: "b",
        c: "c",
        d: "d"
    }

var testObject = {
    a: "",
    b: ""
}

for(keyOne in testObject){ 
  if(mainObject.hasOwnProperty(keyOne)){
     testObject[keyOne]= mainObject[keyOne]
  } 
}
console.log(testObject)
```

Comment: Thanks man, that's what i 'm looking for i got undefined somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for...

```
var mainObject = {
        a: "a",
        b: "b",
        c: "c",
        d: "d"
    }
var testObject = {
    a: "",
    b: ""
}

for(var ob in mainObject){
if(Object.keys(testObject).indexOf(ob)!=-1)
    testObject[ob] = mainObject[ob]
}
console.log(testObject)
```

Comment: Yep, thanx dude.